# Import line getting error in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox

I have a React project that uses OverlayLoader library. Although code runs just fine on Chrome, it gets "TypeError: can't convert null to object" in firefox. After taking some time tracking down the error, I found that it comes from import line where I import OverlayLoader library

```
import OverlayLoader from 'react-overlay-loading/lib/OverlayLoader';
```

There's also "Source map error: request failed with status 404". But that shouldn't matter though. Why this error only occurs in Firefox?

EDIT : This is content of webpack.config.js

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + 'path'});
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: ["./js/app.jsx", "./css/custom.scss", "./css/main.scss"],
  output: {
    path: "public/js",
    publicPath: "/js",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
         test: /\.jsx?|\.js$/,
         exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|neal-react)/,
         loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: "style!css!sass"
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
     alias: {
        querystring: 'querystring-browser'
     }
  },
  plugins: [
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": dotenv.parsed
     })
  ]
};
```

Comment: This is raw js in the browser ? or does it go through a transpiler (babel/webpack etc)?

Comment: It goes through Webpack.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you can check:

1. Do you have a `libraryTarget` in your webpack config? If you, could you try and remove that?
2. Are you using `externals` in your webpack configuration? If so, the package will not be bundles and the browser might not have access to it.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:

Seems like it's a source-map issue. I thought that it might be in your configuration but it isn't. Usually a source-map error is because the browser can't find the source-map I think this is an issue you can report with the repo. It's not your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I dont have any of those in my config file. I posted content of webpack file. You can take a look at it.